# How to push whitespace changes to git without anyone else knowing?

Tags: git

I am very particular about proper indentation and spacing in my code, so it bothers me that a lot of code in the repository I am working on is terribly "dirty".

I want to "clean" the code, but I don't want to be nagged for "making sweeping changes". Is there any way I can hide my whitespace changes from my co-workers? Most of us use gitblit, and some of us use SourceTree. At the end of the day, it's best if nobody knows about these changes.

Comment: You understand that such a method, if one exists, could be used for planting hidden malware?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can hide my whitespace changes from my co-workers?

No, there really isn't. If they receive the change, they will see the change, unless *they* decide to ignore whitespace differences locally in their diff-viewer – you cannot affect such settings remotely. (Your co-workers might even have merge-conflicts as a result of the change.)

In projects such as linux.git, the practice is to only clean up the specific areas (modules, functions, etc) that you're currently working on.

Try to start a trend of using *automated* code formatters (such as "go fmt"); a whole-repository cleanup might become easier if other developers are already used to doing the same for their own code – but this is better discussed elsewhere, such as Workplace.SE.

Comment: I found this pre-commit hook "git diff --ignore-space-at-eol --whitespace=fix HEAD~1 | git apply --ignore-whitespace --whitespace=nowarn" followed by "git commit --no-verify -m <my commit msg>" - would this do it?